# sqldf re-use same connection

Tags: r, sqldf

Is it possible for sqldf re-use same connection for all the queries?  I've an application where I need to set session time zone.  I tried `sqldf("SET SESSION TIME ZONE 'US/Hawaii'")`.  Looks like each query is closing and opening new connection to PostgreSQL.  Thus after `SET SESSION` if I use `sqldf('show time zone')` it still prints `localtime`.

Is there any way to force sqldf to re-use single connection all the time during the code?

Answer (score 2):

I found answer in the documentation.

By calling `sqldf()` in the beginning will create a persistent connection and at the end of code call `sqldf()` which will close the connection.